# Не показывается картинка загруженная из интернета с помощью Picasso

Tags: android, picasso

Какой-то странный формат фото -  в браузере грузит, а в Picasso нет:

```
http://ps1722.weeteam.net/api/images/products/6/16

Picasso.with(this).load("http://ps1722.weeteam.net/api/images/products/6/16").into(imageView);
```

Как мне загрузить это фото в imageView?

Comment: Так ведь сервер авторизацию требует.

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер ожидает аутентификации, а вы делаете GET запрос. А браузер уже хранит в cookies, хедр авторизации поэтому и проходят Get. Вот тоже самое нужно сделать и в Android. Я не регался не знаю, есть подозрения что в API которая по ссылке вся информация есть.

Comment: login: XHKM6A6BLCA5MNYZQBX2GXBAAKSTPMK2
        password: без пароля

Comment: А как можно в строку запроса ввести пароль?